# python pandas function df pointer doesn't change values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to give a function a pointer to an existing df, and trying to copy values from one df to another. but after the function is finished, the values are not assigned to the original object.

how to recreate:

```
import pandas as pd


def copy(df, new_df):
    new_df = df.copy()
    # an example of things that would be modified on new_df
    new_df[0] = "test"
    # just editing df as an example, to show that df is being changed while new_df is not receiving the values 
    df[0] = "test"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mat = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()

    copy(df, new_df)

    print(new_df)
```

if you notice, in this case i am assigning "test" to the first column, in this case it does assign the values to the original object from the pointed object, but new_df do not get the new values.

is this a bug in pandas? or am i doing something wrong?

edit:

the assigning of values to `df[0]` is just an example of how the values do change on the original `df`.
my question is, how do i assign the values from the original df to a new df(it could also be concat, not only copy) without having to return the df and create a new variable which receives the returned value from the function

Comment: You overwrite newdf in the function so of course the original object wont be modified

Comment: @jkr so why does the original object of `df` is being modified?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pandas: `new_df = df.copy()` makes `new_df` a _local_ variable. See for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions): _"The execution of a function introduces a new symbol table used for the local variables of the function. More precisely, all variable assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table ..."_

Answer (score 0):

(Scroll down to `Edit` section to find the answer)

<s>In your case,</s>

1. the copied df is not returned and only scoped to the function. So the new_df outside the function is never assigned the new values.
2. The "test" was assigned to the "df" and not "new_df" after the copying is done. That's why the changes will not reflect when you print the "new_df" even if the function is correct.

Try this out.

```py
import pandas as pd

def copy(df, new_df):
    new_df = df.copy()
    new_df[0] = "test"
    return new_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
  mat = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
  df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
  new_df = pd.DataFrame()
  new_df = copy(df, new_df)
  print(new_df)
```

output

```bash
      0  1  2
0  test  2  3
1  test  5  6
2  test  8  9
```

### Edit

Sorry that I completely missed the part where you needed to have two linked DataFrames. you could just assign the df to a new variable without copying it.

Try this out:

```py
import pandas as pd

def copy(df):
  new_df = df
  df[0] = "test val"
  return df, new_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
  mat = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]

  df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
  df, new_df = copy(df)

  print(df)
  print(new_df)
```

output:

```bash
          0  1  2
0  test val  2  3
1  test val  5  6
2  test val  8  9
          0  1  2
0  test val  2  3
1  test val  5  6
2  test val  8  9
```

Comment: Ah yes. you're right. creating the empty df is not necessary at all. I just edited the function of the originally given code just to point out where the error was.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the assigning to a new column is just to state that the reference do work, i do not need to assign the values to `new_df`. i do not want to assign a new variable for the return of the function, i want it to make the changes to an existing df

Comment: @YanivAkiva refer to the "Edit" and, see if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: i know this will work, but unfortunately i do not want to return the values and then reassign them inside my main\any other function. because although in my example the function is very short and simple, in my real issue it is a very complex function which does a lot of things, so i would rather keep it as a pointer which points to making changes in the original objects.

Comment: Well, if you're intending to use the new values only within the "copy" function, it will work. However, in the given example, you're trying to access the modified variables outside the "copy" function when printing, which won't work unless you return the modified DataFrame objects.

Comment: so why does it work with the original `df`?

Comment: Hopefully, someone would correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, the reference to the original "new_df" is removed when you assign df to new_df. After that, new_df refers to the df object but it works only within the function since it is not the original object you used to have. (new_df is kind of like a new variable defined within the copy function). Now when you're trying to print the new_df outside the copy function, it does not know that it refers to df since you've done it within the function. But the df reference remains intact so it works.

Comment: try printing the new_df within the copy function. you'll see what I mean. Cheers!